# What relation, if any, exists between height and erectile dysfunction?

Tags: biological-parameter, urology, height, body-mass-index-bmi, erectile-dysfunction

For a given BMI, how does height affect erectile dysfunction? I'm curious because height is associated with better cardiovascular health in some studies.